# How to add object to existing class object

Tags: c#

I have a class object:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tag")]
public class Tag
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TagId")]
    public string TagId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "TagTitle")]
    public string TagTitle { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "LocTags")]
public class LocTags
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tag")]
    public Tag[] Tag { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "test")]
public class test
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LocTags")]
    public LocTags LocTags { get; set; }
}
```

And I have data already present like this:

```
test:
    id=1
    Name="abc"
    locTags
       tag
           tagId=1
           tagTitle="xyz"

    id=2
    name="qwe"
    ...
```

I would like to test=1 add new object to Tag, should get result:

```
test:
    id=1
    Name="abc"
    locTags
        tag
            tagId=1
            tagTitle="xyz"

            tagId=2
            tagTitle="pqr"
     id=2
     name="qwe"
     ...
```

How do I do that?

**Edit**

```
List<Tag> tagNew = test.locTags.Tag.ToList();
tagNew.Add(new Tag
{
    TagTitle = "pqr",
    TagId = "2"
});

test.locTags.Tag = tagNew;
```

but the last line gives me error:

> Error  10  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Tag[]'

Comment: How about making Tag[] Tag in LocTasks as List<Tag> and then go by Tag.Add(objnewTag) ?

Comment: Or are you struggling to find out which tag should be added to which test?

Comment: @kassi Thanks for quick response. I tried to do it as you said check my edit. Getting error while trying put that back to existing object

Comment: Try `test.locTags.Tag = tagNew.ToArray();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `Tag[]` Tag as `List<Tag>` and then use `test.LocTagXY.Tags.Add(newTag)`

If you wish to stay with Arrays, use Pradeep Kumar's `test.locTags.Tag = tagNew.ToArray()`